# "Wrap around" to first value after reaching last value

Tags: mysql

Sorry if the title is confusing.

Say I have a playlist of videos with episode_id's of 0 through 20.

The currently playing episode is episode_id 4.

I want to retrieve a list of "More Videos" to prompt the user to keep watching, and also the next episode that's up to watch, like a playlist.  So the list would say "Up Next: Episode 5," then episodes 6 - 20, *but then ideally also episodes 0, 1, 2, and 3.*  So we would wrap around to the beginning episodes again.

Is there an easy MySQL function that I'm not knowing about that can take care of something like this?

EDIT:  I should add that sometimes the episode_id's are not nice and orderly.  The episode_id's of a given show could be 12, 14, 17, 19, 31, and 37, as episode_id is the primary key of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to exploit the boolean ordering, and do this:

```
SELECT * FROM episodes
WHERE ....
ORDER BY episode_id > 4 DESC, episode_id ASC
```

This relies on `episode id > 4 DESC` putting true values before false ones, and then within those two groups you sort by `episode_id ASC`.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I was way too close to the whole situation and had my blinders on :-)